# Mapbox android in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, mapbox

I want to to work on an android application using mapbox for android, i found this link:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-sdk

and i saw that i have to install maven plugin so i could integrate mapbox-sdk apklib to eclipse, i'm new to this can you please tell me how to do it, knowing that there is'n much information about the subject.
and if there is any alternative please inform me, Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Installing Mapbox Android SDK with Gradle will ease your work. Gradle will help you in providing the list of dependencies and will fetch them for you. In the same link which you have mentioned, under the installation section try the link for gradle and install gradle.